# Deploying a vanilla jhipster app on Openshift

Tags: spring, deployment, openshift, liquibase, jhipster

It's been more than a week since I have started to try to deploy a vanilla jhipster application on Openshift. I have tried on Openshift and also on our private corporate instance of Openshift with no success.

I have tried several ways to do it, using the generator yo jhipster:openshift or manually with specific hook.
Using the generator, I have done :

```
yo jhipster (std app java 7 with H2/Mysql and maven)

git init

git add --all

git commit -m "A stupid message ;)."

yo jhipster:openshift
```

Please find the command line to start the app
`[bienvenue-nomadys.kermit.rd.francetelecom.fr repo]\> java -server      -jar target/bienvenue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war      --spring.profiles.active=prod      --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP}      --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT}      --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}      --spring.datasource.username=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}      --spring.datasource.password=${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}`

And this is the log :
`[INFO] com.orange.nomadis.Application - Starting Application on node1.kermit.rd.francetelecom.fr with PID 20787 (started by 54b7c9b8c3215e291500007e in /var/lib/openshift/54b7c9b8c3215e291500007e/app-root/runtime/repo)
[DEBUG] com.orange.nomadis.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.3.RELEASE`
`[WARN] org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Skipping [/var/lib/openshift/54b7c9b8c3215e291500007e/app-root/runtime/repo/target/bienvenue-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] because it does not denote a directory
Processus arrêté`

I don't know what's going wrong and how to trace the execution.
I have no log, nothing.

[Edit]

After changing the execution mode of the build actions_hook in /deploy/openshift/.openshift/action_hooks I have errors with liquid base and spring.

this is the log :

[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.Application - Starting Application on ex-std-node511.prod.rhcloud.com with PID 439180 (started by 54c2066a4382ec19ee0000bb in /var/lib/openshift/54c2066a4382ec19ee0000bb/diy)
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.Application - Running with Spring Boot v1.2.0.RELEASE, Spring v4.1.3.RELEASE
[WARN] org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Skipping [/var/lib/openshift/54c2066a4382ec19ee0000bb/app-root/runtime/repo/target/jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] because it does not denote a directory
[DEBUG] org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges
[INFO] com.mycompany.myapp.config.MetricsConfiguration - Initializing Metrics JMX reporting
[DEBUG] com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Datasource
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.mycompany.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:56) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [jhipster-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:74) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:374) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:150) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:148) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e100c' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e100c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:371) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:136) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:119) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:69) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:216) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:202) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:64) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar!/:8.0.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e100c' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e100c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:646) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.mycompany.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.mycompany.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.mycompany.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2e100c' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2e100c': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:603) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted

.........
lots of exceptions from here to there
.........

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:46)
    at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLogger(LogFactory.java:37)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.(SpringLiquibase.java:134)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration.liquibase(DatabaseConfiguration.java:87)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7370c48f.CGLIB$liquibase$1()
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7370c48f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cd6ab8fb.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.config.DatabaseConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7370c48f.liquibase()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.newInstance(ServiceLocator.java:188)
    at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:44)
    ... 123 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not find implementation of liquibase.logging.Logger
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.findClass(ServiceLocator.java:154)
    at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.newInstance(ServiceLocator.java:186)
    ... 124 more

Answer (score 0):

it seems that problem is caused because the build hook wasn't  executed correctly. sometimes I have gotten a permissions problem for the build hook script. if that is the case execute the following

```
chmod +x .openshift/action_hooks/build
git push
```

Comment: yes, at least you missed one chmod on the build action hook in the /deploy/openshift/.openshift/actions_hooks/.

Comment: even if i change the build execution mode, it's not working. I have exceptions with liquid base (logger not available ?) and spring bean during the application deployment. see below for details.

Comment: Could you share somehow the full logs?, I got a similar issue some weeks ago and behind a ton of similar logs entries there were  a "caused by NullPointerException" entry or something related to setUrl

Comment: you can find my log at https://www.dropbox.com/s/qrnorqwsdjman62/jhipster.log.gz?dl=0 but no trace of NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like maven is trying to autoConfigure your liquibase plugin. I got this error too. I didn't want liquibase to be autoConfigured so I added this just above my main() class declaration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
```

This got rid of my error.